# Hbase fails to create tables

Tags: hbase, hdfs

I used Hbase with Hue to create some tables. After restarting the cluster, I can no longer open/create tables (it's pending). I tried also the Hbase shell but I get this error when trying to scan a table

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: Region hbase:meta,,1 is not online
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegionByEncodedName(HRegionServer.java:2590)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegion(HRegionServer.java:3957)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.get(HRegionServer.java:2738)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:26925)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2175)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer$Handler.run(RpcServer.java:1879)
```

And here you have the exception I get in Hue when trying to create a new table:

```
Mon Jun 30 14:50:04 UTC 2014, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@42af4b1d, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: Region hbase:meta,,1 is not online at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegionByEncodedName(HRegionServer.java:2590) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegion(HRegionServer.java:3957) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.scan(HRegionServer.java:2982) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:26929) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2175) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer$Handler.run(RpcServer.java:1879) Mon Jun 30 14:50:05 UTC 2014, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@42af4b1d, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: Region hbase:meta,,1 is not online at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegionByEncodedName(HRegionServer.java:2590) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegion(HRegionServer.java:3957) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.scan(HRegionServer.java:2982) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:26929) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2175)
```

Answer (score 0):

shut down ZM and HBase

1) for each ZK node: su // login as root cd $ZOOKEEPER_HOME
cp data/myid myid // backup existing myid file to ZooKeeper's home folder rm data/* -Rf rm dadalog/* -Rf mkdir -p data mkdir -p datalog cp myid data/myid // restore the myid backup so no need to recreate myid again

2) for each ZK node: (start ZK )

3) finally (start HBase)

It sometimes throws this error if your config is not proper.
By clearing data and datalog, you should have a very clean ZooKeeper. Hope these help and good luck. Thanks

Comment: thank for you reply. I tried to shutdown and restart as you suggested but I didn't understand the first point with myid

Comment: Could you find the data directory and look into it? The myid should be your pc-name or the default name given while installation.